# Notify the user of serverside changes

Tags: android

I want to notify the user or the device whenever there is a notification to be made.

I want it to be just like facebook, like the notification is suddenly made when you are doing nothing

Is it that there's some kind of broadcast coming in or is it just that the facebook app is constantly looking up at the server for notis?

If it is the former, how can I implement it on android?

Comment: Look at push notifications

Comment: Firebase notification is best choice.

Comment: GCM is the technology you are looking for

Comment: @Shaishav I'm not really looking for push notifications I want it just to be inside the app

Comment: @Amir Thanks I'll take a look at it

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks I'll take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. The one you say when a client app is checking constantly the server is called "polling". Polling is an easy but an inefficient method. Another, more efficient way to do that is using some kind of push notification system. Push notification can work with many techniques (like long polling). In Android (if you are using the Google branch) you have two official push messaging services [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) and [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). The way to go as for now is FCM because is the new version of GCM (think of it as a new and rebranded version). You can have "Facebook like" notifications combining FCM (to get the event from the server) and the [Android Notification Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) (to show the notification in the system).